# Finding the expected value in a random drawing

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

> Suppose the life span of a battery follows exponential distribution with the expected value of 1 year. If three battery are drawn at random and tested until they all fail, what is the expected life span of the battery that failed second?

(There is a duplicate of this question but it's on hold so I'm posting another one)

I'm thinking about setting the expected value of the three batteries as a random vector, say ($v_1, v_2, v_3$). So the one that failed the last would be max$(E(v_1),E(v_2),E(v_3))$. But I'm not sure that if this approach is correct,  and if it is, how should I proceed to find the middle value.

Comment: I would find the expected lifetime of the first to fail plus the expected additional time until the second fails

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can find the expected life span of the first to fail, but I'm not sure how will I find the additional time until the second fails?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You say the expected lifespan of a battery is one year. So does the order change anything? It seems that the expected lifespan of the first, second, and third battery are all still one year, since they are all still "a battery". Or there is some hidden fact here?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. One year is not the "expected life span" but is the expected value of the life span that follows exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $X_j$ be the lifetime of battery $j$, then $X_j \sim Exp(\lambda)$ i.i.d., where $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 1 \text{ year}$.

One could then consider the order statistics $X_{(1)}$, $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$, which are the ordered lifetimes of the batteries, so $X_{(1)} \le X_{(2)} \le X_{(3)}$. We thus need to compute $E[ X_{(2)}]$.

Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_an_exponential_distribution, the random variable $X_{(2)}$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
X_{(2)} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\left( \frac{Z_1}{3} + \frac{Z_2}{2} \right),
\end{equation}

where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are exponential random variables with parameter $1$.

The expected value is then

\begin{align}
E \left[ X_{(2)} \right] &= E \left[\frac{1}{\lambda}\left( \frac{Z_1}{3} + \frac{Z_2}{2} \right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda}\left( E \left[ \frac{Z_1}{3} \right] + E \left[ \frac{Z_2}{2} \right] \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda}\left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{\lambda}.
\end{align}

Therefore, the expected time of failure of the battery failing second is $\frac{5}{6}$ years.